# Redux action return the undefined

Tags: javascript, react-redux, react-hooks

**Question**

Hello, I new on redux.
I want to store the date range (startDate and endDate) on store.
As you see below image, 'start, end' value is returned on the console well, But the Problem is, data doesn't store on action. It keep show, null and undefined.
Can you give me a advise to solving these?

**Attachment**

[image]

**Type.js**

```
export const BookingActionType = {

  BOOKING_CALENDER_DATE: 'BOOKING_CALENDER_DATE',
}
```

**Action**

```
export const getCalenderDate = ({ start, end }) => ({
  type: BookingActionType.BOOKING_CALENDER_DATE,
  payload: { start, end },
});
```

**Reducer.js**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  collection: BOOKING_TYPE_DATA,
  hidden: true,
  guest: 0,
  adult: 0,
  infant: 0,
  startDay: null,
  endDay: null,
};

const bookingReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BookingActionType.BOOKING_CALENDER_DATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        startDay: action.value !== undefined ? action.value : state.startDay,
        endDay: action.value !== undefined ? action.value : state.endDay,
      };
```

**component**

```
function Calender({ props, getUserDate }) {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(moment);
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(moment);
  const [focusedInput, setFocusedInput] = useState(null);

  const handleDatesChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) => {
    setStartDate(startDate);
    setEndDate(endDate);

    let start = new Date(startDate).toLocaleDateString();
    let end = new Date(endDate).toLocaleDateString();
    console.log(start, end);
    console.log(typeof start);
    getUserDate(start, end);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <DateRangePicker
        startDate={startDate}
        startDateId="start_date_id" 
        endDate={endDate} 
        endDateId="end_date_id" 
        onDatesChange={handleDatesChange} 
        customArrowIcon={true}
        noBorder={true}
        block={true}
        focusedInput={focusedInput} 
        onFocusChange={focusedInput => setFocusedInput(focusedInput)} 
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getUserDate: (start, end) => dispatch(getCalenderDate(start, end)),
});
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Calender);
```

Comment: Your action expects object as an argument with `start` and `end` key values `getCalenderDate = ({ start, end })`, but you are invoking it with 2 arguments `(start, end)`


You should change this:

`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getUserDate: (start, end) => dispatch(getCalenderDate(start, end)),
});`


to


`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getUserDate: (start, end) => dispatch(getCalenderDate({ start, end })),
});`

Comment: Thank you! Now I see what was the problem! Curly bracket cause the issue!  I should be aware of  type of Variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your reducer.js file, you are setting the start and end date using `action.value`.

Instead, it should be `action.payload`. Also in your action function is expecting variables not an object so replace `({start,end})` with `(start,end)`. also I did some more improvements I hope they help

Copy-paste this code and it should work

**Action**

```
export const getCalenderDate = (start, end) => ({
  type: BookingActionType.BOOKING_CALENDER_DATE,
  payload: { start, end },
});
```

**Reducer.js**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  collection: BOOKING_TYPE_DATA,
  hidden: true,
  guest: 0,
  adult: 0,
  infant: 0,
  startDay: null,
  endDay: null,
};

    const bookingReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case BookingActionType.BOOKING_CALENDER_DATE:
          return {
            ...state,
            startDay: action.payload ? action.payload.start : state.booking.startDay,
            endDay: action.payload ? action.payload.end : state.booking.endDay,
          };
        }
     }
```

Comment: Wow..! It works! I really appreciate it. 
Also Thank you for your explaination now I know what was the problem
 =)